# Perform overridePendingTransition to start an Activity from Service Class?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm unable to perform a `overridePendingTransition` to start an Activity from a service class. I'm opening an activity from service class which is working perfectly but I want to start that activity with a transition.
this code is written in service class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
```

but `overridePendingTransition` is not working its shows an error log

```
"android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

try using overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out,R.anim.fade_in); 
in your Activiy --> OnCreate()

So it will always animate irrespective of from where it is been called.

Comment: use it after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: I had to use it before `super.onCreate()` in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to call overridePendingTransition method on your activity istance, it looks like activity here is your application instance.

Comment: android studio is not allowing me to write directly in service class. it says
can't resolve error 'overridePendingTransition'

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: What is your Activity1 and Activity2?

Comment: Activity1 is a service class and Activity2 is an Activity. its working perfect without overridePendingTransition but I want to call the Activity2 smoothly.